# How to create long press event in phonegap android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created and android phone gap app.what i want to do is i have an delete button in my  app in which  when a we long press a button it should display a conform message that "Do you want to delete the account " We i use a on click function its working correctly its not working on long press can any tell who to  do this.
here is the code that i had used for longpress

```
$(document).on(function(){
$("#taphold").bind("taphold",function(){
    var hi=confirm("Do you really want to delete data");
    if(hi==true) {
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(deleterecord,[id]);
            alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
            parent.location='file:///android_asset/www/index.html';
        });
    }else{
        alert("Data not deleted");
    }
});});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a notification inside the button click listner...

```
     // process the confirmation dialog result
    function onConfirm(button) {
    alert('You selected button ' + button);
    }

    // Show a custom confirmation dialog
    //
    function showConfirm() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
    );
    }
```

For more info check..[Phone gap doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

Comment: hey thanks for rply but its working same as onclick function what i want is it show display message only when user long press button..